# Karate: Scenario fails if contains __arg and run in 'stand-alone' mode

Tags: karate

I have faced a problem when I try to run a Scenario containing built-in `__arg` variable as 'stand-alone' (not 'called'), then my test fails with an error (I do not `@ignore` the called one as in order to use it in both 'called' and 'stand-alone' modes):

```
evaluation (js) failed: __arg, javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "__arg" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
stack trace: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
```

Following two simple features should be enough to reproduce.

*called-standalone.feature*:

```
Feature: Called + Stand-alone Scenario
  Scenario: Should not fail on __arg when run as stand-alone
    * def a = __arg
    * print a
```

*caller.feature*:

```
Feature: Caller
  Scenario: call without args
    When def res = call read('called-standalone.feature')
    Then match res.a == null

  Scenario: call with args
    When def res = call read('called-standalone.feature') {some: 42}
    Then match res.a == {some: 42}
```

Putting these two features into the skeleton project and run `mvn test` will show an error.

I'm expecting this should work as the docs say that "‘called’ Karate scripts ... can behave like ‘normal’ Karate tests in ‘stand-alone’ mode".

> ‘called’ Karate scripts don’t need to use any special keywords to ‘return’ data and can behave like ‘normal’ Karate tests in ‘stand-alone’ mode if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Karate variables have to be "defined" at run time. This is a rule which can not be relaxed.

So you should re-design your scripts. The good thing is you can use `karate.get()` to set a "default value".

```
* def a = karate.get('__arg', null)
```

That should answer your question.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks for the rapid response!